# Showing a Fredholm map is a bijection

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $S\in \mathcal{B}(E,F)$ is a Fredholm map where $E,F$ are Banach spaces. Also let $P$ be a compact projection, i.e. $P\in \mathcal{K}(E)$ and $P(P(x))= P(x)$ such that $P(E) = ker(S)$.

Let $\hat{S}: \ker(P) \rightarrow S(E)$ by $\hat{S}(x) = S(x)$ for all $x\in ker(P)$.

I am trying to show that $\hat{S}$ is a bijection but I can't get very far. How should I go about this?

Comment: isn't it direclty by Fredholm's alternative?

Comment: im not sure I am following

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FredholmAlternative.html